# Upload video tab removed/banned

Tags: google-plus

Ok, so 2 or 3 times a week i share videos uploading em directly in g+, and as i read in some other posts from stackoverflow, you can upload an unlimited amount of videos this way as long as they are 1080p or lower and last 15mins or less.

The thing is, 2 days ago, the upload feature got removed from my account (only this one), i didn't get any notification of any miss-behaviors, neither had any of my post flagged or removed... (ever, my account is like 3 months old).

So, what could it be?, how could i address this problem?

Comment: Have you checked to see that you have, indeed, _not_ run out of storage?

Comment: It's 0% used acording to my g+ settings, same for gmail and google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may take a little time to get a response, your best bets are doing the following:

1. Post a message and be sure to include `+Google+ Help` in the message. These are the Community managers for Google+ and they are pretty good about replying to problems such as this - although sometimes it takes them a while to reply.
2. Post a message in the Google+ Discuss community at https://plus.google.com/communities/115758385206378551362 where some of Google+'s Top Contributors, as well as the Community Managers, may be able to help.

Comment: Ty, i'll try that an see how it goes.

Comment: OK, it was a very dumb mistake... but at least is working now, your answer was very helpful:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/117563322883126354392/posts/GL9oC5h6ok6